# How to combine groupby and sort in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting, group-by

I am trying to get one result per 'name' with all of the latest data, unless the column is blank. In R I would have used group_by, sorted by timestamp and selected the latest value for each column. I tried to do that here and got very confused. Can someone explain how to do this in Python? In the example below my goal is:

```
   col2                 date name
1    4  2018-03-27 15:55:29  bil #latest timestamp with the latest non-blank col4 value
```

Heres my code so far:

```
d = {'name':['bil','bil','bil'],'date': ['2018-02-27 14:55:29', '2018-03-27 15:55:29', '2018-02-28 19:55:29'], 'col2': [3,'', 4]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df2)

grouped = df2.groupby(['name']).sum().reset_index()
print(grouped)
sortedvals=grouped.sort_values(['date'], ascending=False)
print(sortedvals)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
df3 = df2[df2['col2'] != ''].sort_values('date', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('name')

#   col2                 date name
# 2    4  2018-02-28 19:55:29  bil
```

However, the dataframe you provided and output you desire seem to be inconsistent.

Comment: That did solve the problem in my sample data, unfortunately for my actual code dropping rows with a missing col2 isnt an option because they might still have other good data :)

Comment: @Rilcon42, you could just assign the result to a new variable, e.g. `df3` (as in my update). That way your original dataframe is unchanged.